# Do Application Services reside within a Service Layer?

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design

Application Service fulfills the commands issued by clients (ie presentation layer) by making and coordinating calls to the Workflows, Infrastructure Services, Domain Services, and Domain Entities.

I assume Application Service reside within Service Layer?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In DDD, Application Services are part of the Application Layer. Service Layer is Martin Fowler's name for the Application Layer.